# How to resolve references in python/elemttree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am new with python elementree and xml. I want to extract information from an XML that contains references, but findall() does not seem to resolve them.

My simplified XML:

```
<client>
  <accounts>
    <account>
      <name>BANK1</name>
      <transactions>
      ...
      </transactions>
     </account>
     <account>
      <name>BANK2</name>
      <transactions>
      ...
      </transactions>
     </account>
     <account reference="../account/transactions/account-transaction[7]/crossEntry/portfolio/transactions/portfolio-transaction[12]/crossEntry/account"/>
</accounts>
<portfolios>
<portfolio reference="../../accounts/account/transactions/account-transaction[7]/crossEntry/portfolio"/>
<portfolio reference="../../accounts/account[2]/transactions/account-transaction/crossEntry/portfolio"/>
</portfolios>
</client>
```

The following code is only returning the two BANK1 and BANK2 accounts, but not the refereced BANK3 account

```
dfcols = ['name']
acct = pd.DataFrame(columns=dfcols)

for idx, account in enumerate(PP.pp.findall(".//accounts/account")):
    if account is not None:
        acc_name =  account.find('name').text if account.find('name') is not None else ""
        acct = acct.append(pd.Series([acc_name], index=dfcols),ignore_index=True)
        
acct
```